How to match a replacement thermal fuse
I have to replace a thermal fuse on a small refrigerator defroster.  The fuse has an orange cap and the information on it is as follows:
SHENG PING
SPF70
TG 73 degrees C
10A  50V        (I think these should be 150V and 125V with the 1 just worn off.  There 15A  25V         seems to be room for the 1)
The Voltage going to the fuse is 120V. I understand the 1st code is the manufacturer and the 2nd is their part #, the 3rd is the cut off temp, and the last 2 are the working voltage.
How close do I have to be to the 73 degrees +/- ?  Does the orange cap color mean anything?  Is there anything else I need to know?
Thank you, I appreciate any help you can give me.

150 V rating for a 120 V appliance seems reasonable. No idea on the color code though.

A quick search finds a Shenping datasheet.
The SPF70 is rated at 10A/250V (not 150V which would not be usable for worldwide applications) and as follows:

Note the relevant safety agency approvals and temperature tolerance.
Keep in mind when musing substitutions that this is a safety device, typically the last device in a chain, and a device that may prevent emissions of toxic smoke or even prevent your house from becoming a funeral pyre.

Thanks so much for your help.

I've researched based on your specs and I think this would fit your needs.
https://fr.farnell.com/multicomp-pro/mp001618/fusible-thermique/dp/3285086
This fuse is rated for 10A, 250V with a 73°C working temperature.
I suggest a replacement from a trusted seller, this components must be approved and certified to work as expected.
Hope it can help.

Thanks so much for your help.
